# Can't deserialize object containing LocalDate received from AMQP messaging

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, amqp

I try to send an object via AMQP messaging (RabbitMQ) but when I receive the message the converter raise a JsonMappingException because it was unable to deserialize that message.

**Order.java:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.LocalDateDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.ser.LocalDateSerializer;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Flaviu Cicio on 07.07.2016.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_order", schema = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private Long userId;


    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate date;



    @OneToMany(mappedBy="byOrder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private List<OrderProduct> products;

    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(Long id, Long userId, List<OrderProduct> products, LocalDate date) {

        this.id = id;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.products = products;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Long getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public List<OrderProduct> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<OrderProduct> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }


    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", userId=" + userId +
                ", date=" + date +
                '}';
    }

}
```

**RabbitConfiguration.java:**

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        template.setRoutingKey("order-queue");
        template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return template;
    }
    @Bean
    public Queue userQueue() {
        return new Queue("order-queue", false);
    }

}
```

**OrderController.java:**

```
import com.orderservice.service.OrderService;
import com.shopcommon.model.Order;
import com.shopcommon.model.OrderProduct;
import com.shopcommon.model.Product;
import com.shopcommon.model.User;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/orders")
public class OrderController {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OrderController.class);

    @Autowired
    OrderService orderService;

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    AmqpAdmin rabbitAdmin;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Order> getOrders(){
        return orderService.get();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Order getOrder(@PathVariable("id") Long id){

        logger.info("Returned order: " +  orderService.getById(id));

        return orderService.getById(id);
    }

    /**
     * Persist a new order received from amqp messaging
     *
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Order createOrder(){

        Order order = (Order) rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert("order-queue");

        logger.info("Created a new order: " +  order);

        return orderService.create(order);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteOrder(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        orderService.delete(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Order updateOrder(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Order order){

        List<OrderProduct> products = order.getProducts();
        products.stream().forEach(orderProduct -> orderProduct.setOrder(order));
        order.setProducts(products);

        return orderService.update(order);
    }

    /**
     * Get user from a specific order
     *
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getOrderUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        Order order = orderService.getById(id);

        rabbitAdmin.purgeQueue("user-queue", false);

        try {
            logger.info("Requested from user-service user from order with id " +  id);
            logger.info("USER ID " +  order.getUserId());

            URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:9999/user-service/users/" + order.getUserId());
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.getResponseCode();


            User user = (User)rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert("user-queue");

            logger.info("Received from user-service: " +  user);

            return user;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        logger.info("No user found!");
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get products from a specific order
     *
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Product> getOrderProducts(@PathVariable("id") Long id){

        rabbitAdmin.purgeQueue("product-queue", false);

        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

        logger.info("Requested from product-service products from order with id " +  id);

        Order order = orderService.getById(id);

        order.getProducts().forEach(orderProduct -> {
            try {
                URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:9999/product-service/products/" + orderProduct.getProductId());
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                con.getResponseCode();

                products.add((Product) rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert("product-queue"));

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        });

        logger.info("Received from product-service a number of " +  products.size() + " products");

        return products;
    }


}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
2016-07-13 09:40:27.668 ERROR 5108 --- [nio-8004-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to convert Message content] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: expected String, Number or JSON Array
 at [Source: {"id":null,"userId":1,"products":[],"date":{"dayOfMonth":13,"dayOfWeek":"WEDNESDAY","dayOfYear":195,"month":"JULY","monthValue":7,"year":2016,"hour":9,"minute":40,"nano":199000000,"second":27,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}}; line: 1, column: 44] (through reference chain: com.shopcommon.model.Order["date"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:261) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.wrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1340) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.LocalDateDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateDeserializer.java:65) ~[jackson-datatype-joda-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.LocalDateDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateDeserializer.java:15) ~[jackson-datatype-joda-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:490) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2871) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter.convertBytesToObject(Jackson2JsonMessageConverter.java:122) ~[spring-amqp-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter.fromMessage(Jackson2JsonMessageConverter.java:92) ~[spring-amqp-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(RabbitTemplate.java:819) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.orderservice.controller.OrderController.createOrder(OrderController.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:281) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a Joda class and not a `java.time.LocalDateTime`?  Regardless, it definitely contains both a date and a time, so you probably need `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalDate` in either case.  Not posting as an answer because this is just a guess based on the stack trace and a quick look at GrepCode.

Comment: Thanks @JimGarrison, you were right, i sent a `java.time.LocalDateTime` instead of a `org.joda.time.LocalDate`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, you should add the following maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Second, you should update your MessasgeConverter bean with this:

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter messageConverter()
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules();

    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(mapper);
}
```

After this update you don't need to use "JsonSerialize" annotations.

Comment: The `setJsonObjectMapper` is deprecated. Use the constructor: `new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper)`

Comment: You don't need to instantiate the ObjectMapper yourself. You can inject it directly `messageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper);`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is still looking for a answer they can copy paste in their application :)

The code below asks spring to inject its default object mapper, then asks it to register all the modules in the classpath. So make sure you have included 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310' in your pom or gradle file.

```
@Configuration
    @Slf4j
    public class SpringInternalObjectMapperConfig {
    
        /*
        Java 8 date/time type `java.time.LocalDateTime` not supported by default:
         add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling
    
         */
    
        @Bean
        public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter(ObjectMapper springInternalObjectMapper) {
            log.info("Updating spring's object mapper.");
            springInternalObjectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
            return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(springInternalObjectMapper);
        }
    
    }
```